# Is there a way to dynamically create CSS Grids for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I am creating a php website where I pull content from a database and build the html divs in my output to the page as needed. I then format the page using CSS grids. This process works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari. I cannot get it to behave correctly in Internet Explorer 11.

I am trying to incorporate -ms in my code. For some reason when viewed in Internet Explorer my grid is superimposed in the first row of the first column. I took my working code and ran it through Autoprefixer CSS which gave me nothing helpful.

Sample of HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="head">Title of grid displayed here</div>
//Inside content I build <div> based on return from db//
<div class="content">
            //the info <div> stopped at the end of the loop//
        <div id="info"></div> 
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Sample of CSS

```
.main {
/*Internet Explorer*/
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns:100%;
-ms-grid-rows: auto 20px auto;
/*All other browsers*/
display: grid;
grid-template-columns:100%;
grid-gap: 20px 20px;
margin-bottom: 5%;
grid-template-areas:
"head"
"content";
}

.head {
/*Internet Explorer*/
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-row: 1;
-ms-grid-column: 1fr;
/*All other browsers*/
grid-area: head;
display: grid;
margin: 2% 0 2% 0;
text-align: center;
}

.content {
/*Internet Explorer*/
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-row: 3;
-ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
-ms-grid-column-span: 1;
/*All other browsers*/
 grid-area: content;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px , 1fr));
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 2;
 grid-row-gap: 10px;
 grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

#info {
outline: solid #515151;
}

.info{
 grid-area: info;

}
```

The output looks great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and even Edge. I just cannot get it to work in IE.

Comment: Your auto prefixer will not help you. The problem is that `auto-fit` is not supported in IE11. I had a similar issue as you do some time ago, but I ended up writing a JS fallback for IE. Even though, that's not the best approach as well, as if you have too many contents displayed, the performance can drop massively.

Comment: Try to refer this link may help to get some idea to make it work for IE. Ref: https://blog.datawrapper.de/prefixed-css-grid-with-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using CSS Grid only in browsers that support Grid, in other cases I use Flexbox.

Flexbox Fallback for CSS Grid Layout

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 30%; /* IE11 */
  margin: 1.6%; /* IE11 */
  background: rgb(242, 248, 207);
  border: 4px dashed black;
}
/* This will only activate the Grid in browsers that support it */
@supports (display: grid) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .grid-item {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(243, 242, 242);
    margin: 0;/* We will use grid-gap instead of margin */
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item">6</div>
      <div class="grid-item">7</div>
      <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    </div>
```

I think we can get better results using media queries, I hope I have helped you .

Comment: This was the perfect solution. IE is such a pain.